"Vetternwirtschaft" gendergerecht
Ich würde gerne wissen, wie man das Wort "Vetternwirtschaft" gendergerecht schreibt.
Soweit mir bekannt ist, sind "Vettern" wengistens im Plural zwar eigentlich Verwandte beiderlei Geschlechts, denn das Wort kann entweder die männlichen oder die männlichen und weiblichen Verwandten bedeuten (generisches Maskulinum), aber erstens bin ich mir darüber nicht sicher (ich habe das Wort erst lange nach Erwerb meiner Sprachkompetenz das erste Mal gehört) und zweitens soll genau das ja in korrekter Sprache vermieden werden.
Es ist schließlich nicht einzusehen, daß weibliche Vettern, sofern sie ebenfalls ungerechtfertigt bevorzugt werden, sich mitgemeint fühlen müssen ohne explizit auch als korrupt angesprochen zu werden. Wenn man von "Tag" spricht, dann meint man ja auch die Nacht ausdrücklich nicht mit, sondern exklusiv die Zeit, in der die Sonne scheint. Meint man 24-Stunden-Perioden, dann sagt man korrekt "Tage und Nächte".
Das weibliche Pendant zu "Vetter" ist "Base", aber dieses Wort ist heute ungebräuchlich. Darüber hinaus läuft "Base" Gefahr, als ein Synonym für "Lauge" (also das Gegenteil von Säure) mißverstanden zu werden. Es steht also füglich zu bezweifeln, ob

Vettern- und Basenwirtschaft

so aufgefaßt werden würde, wie es gemeint wäre, nämlich gendergerechter Nepotismus/Neptitismus.
Als Alternative kämen vielleicht die modernen, aus dem Französischen entlehnten Bezeichnungen für diesen Verwandtschaftsgrad in Frage:

Cousinen- und Cousinswirtschaft

aber auch hier ist nicht sicher, ob das in der intendierten Weise verstanden würde. Dazu fragt sich, wie sich unentschiedene nichtbinäre Transwesen und Diverse (Divergierende?) fühlen mögen, wenn man ihnen generaliter die Fähigkeit, sich durch Verwandtschaftsbeziehungen ungerechte Vorteile zu verschaffen, durch Nichterwähnung abspricht. Also vielleicht:

Cous*@Innen-wirtschaft

oder auch noch ein paar weitere Sonderzeichen und Binnenkapitalien?
Es wäre natürlich möglich, die genauen Familiaritätsrelationen, die zu der Bevorzugung führen, wegzulassen und statt dem anrüchigen "Vettern" das allgemeine "Verwandt(-schafts)-" zu nehmen:

Verwandtenwirtschaft (Verwandtschaftswirtschaft)

Auch diese Form ist aber problembehaftet: "verwandt" ist eine Partizipbildung von "verwenden" (das bedeutete auf Mittelhochdeutsch nicht nur "benützen", sondern auch "Umgang miteinander haben", figurativ "sich einander zuwenden") und da "geschlechtsneutral" (M.P. Ängsal) das Partizip Präsens ("Studierende", "Mietende", "Demonstrierende", ...) ist, müßte es dann wohl

Verwendendenwirtschaft

heißen.
Auch eine (zugegebenermaßen kurze) Internetrecherche ergab keine Hinweise zur Lösung des Problems.

Was mitgemeint ist oder nicht ergibt sich in der Regel aus dem Kontext. Ein Tag hat 24 Stunden, wie sich das in Tag und Nacht spaltet ist erstmal egal. Wenn man allerdings davon ausgeht das man nachts schläft dann kann "tagsüber" schnell zu dem Zeitraum werden wo's hell ist. Allerdings womöglich auch nur so zwischen 12 Uhr und 18 Uhr, weil davor könnte es auch morgends und abends sein. Und wenn man eine Gruppe Männer mit "So Mädels" anspricht sind die da auch mitgemeint. Problematisch kann es werden bei unklarem Kontext und klarer Genus oder bei Ausschluss durch bewusste Unklarheit.

@haxor789: wenn bei zB "Ärzten" sich Frauen nicht mitgemeint fühlen, weil "der Arzt" gammatikalisch maskulin ist, dann ergibt sich zwar, was mitgemeint ist (nämlich Ärztinnen) auch aus dem Kontext, aber das ist - so zumindest die Begründung für "gendergerechte" Sprache - unerheblich.

Naja das Problem ist ja das es ohne Kontext nicht eindeutig ist ob "Ärzte" die Gesammtheit der Menschen mit der entsprechenden Approbation bezeichnet oder nur den männlichen Teil davon oder eine deutlich kleinere Gruppe von Ärzten die aber alle männlich sind. Und das Genus letztere präferiert. Wobei das größere Problem vermutlich der Stereotyp von "Arzt und Krankenschwester" ist, wo die Geschlechterrollen schon so klar verteilt wurden das sie Teil der Berufsbezeichnung geworden sind.

@haxor789 Die Ärzte sind alle männlich und machen gute Musik :) Aber es gibt im Heilunsgberuf selbstverständlich nicht nur Koryphäen, sondern auch Koryphäeriche

Sag einfach "Nespotismus" - da braucht es ein Latinum, um das generische Maskulinum herauszupräparieren. Dabei sind die Lateiner gar nicht so auf Kongruenz zwischen genus und sexus fixiert - ich sage nur "nauta, der Seemann" und "agricola, der Bauer"

@HagenvonEitzen: Naja, ohne Latinum würde ich vielleicht nicht wissen, das "nepos" maskulin ist und "der Neffe" heißt, während die feminine Nichte "neptis" heißt. Habe ich eigentlich auch im Text erwähnt, aber das war wahrscheinlich zu weit unten.

Wer versucht das negative belegte Wort "Vetternwirtschaft" den weiblichen Lesern gegendert vorzulegen, wird von den Amazonen (oder Amazoninnen?) geschreddert. Muß man neuerdings auch das Worte "Studenten" in "Studerpel/Studenten" vergendern? Ist die gegenderierte Version von "Base" nicht "Säure"?

TLDR: Lass es, oder nutze ein Synomnym wie Klüngel oder Klanwirtschaft
Es gab schon viele Versuche, als männlich gelesene Erstbestandteile von Komposita zu ersetzen, in Worten wie Mannschaft oder Herrschaft. Das Problem dabei ist aber, dass die Erstbestandteile meist gar nicht wegen ihrer Männlichkeit dastehen, sondern wegen ihren anderen Bedeutungen, und eine Ersetzung nicht offensichtlich ist. Zudem sind die Wörter zusammengewachsen und bedeuten mehr als die Summe ihrer Teile. Vetterwirtschaft ist ja nicht eine Wirtschaft basierend auf Vettern. Durch die Ersetzung wird dann bis zur Unerkenntlichkeit entstellt, wie in Cousinswirtschaft.
Solche absichtlichen Ersetzungen (z.B. auch Frauschaft) wirken gekünstelt und erklärungswürdig und sind, Stand jetzt, definitiv weit vom Mainstream entfernt. Für mich klingt Vettern- und Basenwirtschaft mehr nach einer Karrikatur von Gendersprachbemühungen à la Fahrradständer*innen als nach einem Wort, das jemand ernsthaft einsetzen würde.
Zudem ist es auch unklar, was eine Veränderung hier bewirken soll, schließlich denkt niemand bei Vetternwirtschaft tatsächlich an Vettern. Selbst bei einem Herrenrad steht mehr das Rad im Vordergrund als ein mutmaßlicher Besitzer oder eine Besitzerin. Die typische Begründung, an andere Geschlechter werde nicht gedacht, zieht hier einfach nicht so gut.
Sollte man sich trotzdem an dem ersten Bestandteil stören, wäre meine Empfehlung, Synonyme zu benutzen. So gibt es die Günstlingswirtschaft, den Filz oder den Klüngel, die aber weniger auf Verwandschaftsverhältnisse abziehen denn auf Freundschaften. Dafür gäbe es aber die Klanwirtschaft, mit der Einschränkung, dass nur Familienstrukturen einiger Kulturen als Kläne angesehen werden.
Kleine Anmerkung: Verwandt ist ein Partizip, und damit ist die Verwandten bereits geschlechtsneutral. Es gibt absolut keine Notwendigkeit, mit Biegen und Brechen ein Partizip I draus zu machen.

Danke für die Antwort, aber ich denke, wenn man bei Berufsbezeichnungen das grammatikalische Genus dem biologischen Sexus unterordnet, dann sollte man das auch be Verbrechenstatbeständen tun. Also statt "Massenmörder" eben "MassenmörderInnen" oder, besser, "Massenmordende". Kleine Gegenanmerkung: der Plural von "Klan" ist "Klans". Es besteht kein Grund, auf Biegen und Brechen einen Umlaut einzubauen. ;-)

@bakunin Ich glaube, du hast das mit dem Partizip nicht verstanden: Es gibt keine "VerwandtInnen", "Verwandte" ist bereits geschlechtsneutral.

Mein Einwand war nicht auf das Thema Partizip bezogen (das habe ich durchaus verstanden), sondern auf den Hinweis, das Gendern durch Synonyme zu umgehen. Wir umgehen den Gegensatz "Bürger-Bürgerin" ja auch nicht durch "StaatsbürgerInnenschaftsinhabende", sondern sagen "Bürgerinnen und Bürger" (unter sträflicher Vernachlässigung der anderen ~300 Geschlechter, die Facebook sonst noch kennt, aber sei's drum).

@Bakunin: Es gibt keine spezielle Grammatik für Berufsbezeichnungen. Die Regeln sind die gleichen, die bei Bewegungsabläufen (Schwimmer, Reiter, Läufer, Geher), bei Funktionen (Vorstand, Aufsichtsrat, Leiter, ...) und anderen Substantivierungen (Träumer, Schläfer, Säufer, ...) zur Anwendung kommen. Es gibt auch keine Kongruenz von Geschlecht in der Sprache, in der es 3 gibt (männlich, weiblich, sächlich) und Geschlecht in der Biologie (da gibt es bei Säugetieren 2) oder Geschlecht als soziale Rolle (Gender). Es gibt auch keine Unterordnung.

@bakunin: "ich denke, wenn man bei Berufsbezeichnungen das grammatikalische Genus dem biologischen Sexus unterordnet, dann sollte man das auch bei Verbrechenstatbeständen tun" - bei auf die Personen bezogenen Begriffen stimme ich dir ja zu, nur bezeichnet "Vettern" in "Vetternwirtschaft" ja gar nicht die Personen, um die es geht. Insofern stimme ich auch der Aussage aus der Antwort hier, dass "niemand (...) an Vettern (...) denkt", nicht so ganz zu - doch, man denkt an Vettern, weil Vetternwirtschaft ein Verhalten ist, wie es vielleicht unter eng vertrauten Vettern zu Tage tritt, ...

... aber eben nicht in der Annahme, dass es tatsächlich Vettern sind, die diese in einem konkreten Fall betreiben.
